# character comparison in c and break

Tags: c

My issue here is that I'm not really sure how character comparison works in this specific code:

```
while (1) {
    scanf("%c", &c);
    if (c == 'c')
        printf("working\n");
    else {
        printf("Not working\n");
        break;
    }
    printf("not-not-working\n");
}
```

I'm interested in why the output of this program is:

- If I enter "c", output is: working, not working, not-not-working
- If I enter anything else: not working, not-not-working.

My question is, can I compare character like this, or do I have to use `strcmp()`?
Also how does this `break` work?

PS: I've searched for other answers and tutorials, but kinda got stuck on my own problem.

Comment: Since `not-not-working` is out of the `if` it will always show up. Put a `break;` after the first `if`. PS: `return 0` might work as well.

Comment: You may want to print `c` as well as the return value of `scanf` in order to better see what's going on in your code.

Comment: yes, lets say its already initialized.

Comment: Note that the claimed output does not match what the program actually produces.  It is also best to check that `scanf()` worked; you don't know when it gets EOF because you don't check its return value. You need to check the return value from an input function every time — things go wrong (sometimes horribly wrong) when you don't.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that scanf will return as long as there is characters in the input buffer. And the buffer isn't flushed before you press enter.

So your loop runs until the buffer is empty, or you hit the break statement.

Changing your code to:

```
int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
  char c[BUFSIZ];

  while(1){
    scanf("%c",c);
    fprintf(stderr,"Input was: '%c'\n",c[0]);
    if(c[0] == 'c')
          printf("working\n");
    else
    {
          printf("Not working\n");
          break; // This will exit the while loop if the character is not 'c'
    }
    printf("not-not-working\n"); // This will always print on every iteration
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Gives the output, when entering 'c' + [ENTER]:

```
c
Input was: 'c'
working
not-not-working
Input was: '
'
Not working
```

You can fix this example by using sscanf instead of scanf, and then just checking the first character, c[0].

Comment: Nice job; I agree that the reported output in the question doesn't match the output that the program should generate — and you've saved me having to compile the code to show that.  Also good echoing the input; that is a very powerful technique for debugging code — it tells you what your program is actually seeing rather than what you think it should be seeing.  The difference (here, the newline) is often crucial to understanding the program.

Comment: Thanks. 
I guess the trick here is to use sscanf, and just check the first character. I'm not really comfortable in implementing command line interfaces this way, and usually prefer to use gengetopt for everything. [GenGetOpt](http://www.gnu.org/software/gengetopt/gengetopt.html)

Comment: This has undefined behavior in the `fprintf(stderr,"Input was: '%s'\n",c);`.  `c[BUFSIZ]` is not initialized and so when printing `c` as a string, it is not known to be `\0` terminated.

Comment: Thanks Chux for pointing that out. Fixed in the post now. It's xtill kind of awkward with my half-way intention of using sscanf to fix his problem. Feel free to improve the example.

Answer (score 1):

Direct answers to your questions:

> Can I compare characters with `==`?

Yes.

> How does `break` work?

A `break` from within a `while` loop will cause the loop to exit immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading a character using scanf. When you press 'c' you also press enter for scanf to accept your input. Now you have 2 characters in the buffer.

On 1st iteration the value of c is 'c' and it prints 'working' then comes out of if block and prints 'not-not-working'. On second iteration, the value of c is '\n' which is not equal to 'c' therefore it goes to else block and prints 'Not working'. Then break exits the while loop.

To prove this try pressing 'cccccccccccc' when scanf reads for c and you will see it will print 'working', 'not-not-working' several times as many as the number of occurrence of 'c'.

EDIT:

Note, press and hold c until you have plenty of c without space in between then press enter.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%c", &c)` is scanning in `c` and `<Enter>` as 2 separate characters.

Keyboard I/O is typically buffered.   So `scanf()` see nothing until `c` and `<Enter>` are pressed.  `scanf()` read the `c` on the first pass and `<Enter>` (aka `\n`) on the second.  Changing to `scanf(" %c", &c)` will first scan and discard any leading whitespace, including `\n`.

Change

```
scanf("%c", &c);
```

to

```
char c;   
scanf(" %c", &c);
```

---

Q: can I compare character like this, or do I have to use strcmp()?
A: Yes you can compare as posted is `c` is a `char`.  `strcmp()` is not necessary.

Q: Also how does this break work?
A: Exit the current `for/while/do` loop or `switch` statement and proceed to the next statement.

Answer (score 0):

your two question have answered by people above.what I want to say is function "scanf",you should be careful about that,lear it totally~maybe below code you will interest:

```
while(1)
{
   scanf("%d",&a);     //d is int type
   printf("%c",c);
}
```

when you input a charater,can you explain why the output?